# Flask: Different database backends for different subdomains?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My application caters to multiple customers using subdomains and uses a common database for infrastructure management and customer specific databases for each customer. I am developing this using python `Flask` framework and using `flask-sqlalchemy` plugin.

For a single customer scenario, I can handle this using two `sqlalchemy` binds in configuration (one for customer db, one for housekeeping db).
But when I add multiple customers, I want them use customer specific configurations to get right database for customer bind. It is important for me to keep customers data in their own databases for compliance requirements.

One way I can achieve the functionality is to deploy as many web apps as there are customers, but that is not scalable.

I explored using `blueprints`, but blueprints are used to have different views for each blueprint. For me, the views remain same for all customers. I just want them to access different databases based on the subdomain. Also, it may not be a good idea to go on creating blueprints as customer list grows. How to achieve this with a single flask app, using same views and model definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You could place some code in a function wrapped with the decorator `@app.before_request` to check if the user is authenticated and then work out the correct database based upon Flask's `request.url` and store it in Flask's global `g` object.